# Retrive the value from Semantic UI drop down item?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Is there any way to retrieve the dropdown items value? when the on-click handler gets called it doesn't the value, Instead, it returns the text and IMG component.
And also the on onchange handler attached to dropdown never gets triggered

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown, Item } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./currency.style.css";

const CurrencyConverter = ({ currencyDetails, initialData }) => {
  const handleSelection = (e) => {
    alert();
  };

  return (
    <div className="currency-form">
      <div className="selected-Country">
        <img src={initialData.flag} width="30px" height="30px" />
      </div>
      <Dropdown
        inline
        text={initialData.currency}
        
      >
        <Dropdown.Menu
          
        >
          {currencyDetails.map((item) => (
            <Dropdown.Item
              key={Math.random()}
              text={item.currencyName}
              image={item.flag}
              style={{ height: "70px", fontSize: "17px" }}
              onClick={(event, item) => {
                console.log(item);
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ currency: { currencyDetails } }) => ({
  currencyDetails,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(CurrencyConverter);
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is to assign the 'value' as part of the Dropdown.Item:

```
            <Dropdown.Item
              key={Math.random()}
              text={item.currencyName}
              image={item.flag}
              value={item.value}
              style={{ height: "70px", fontSize: "17px" }}
              onClick={(event, item) => {
                console.log(item);
              }}
            />
```

Then you can grab the 'value' from item passed by the onClick event.

```
onClick={(event, item) => console.log(item.value)}
```

So long as you set the 'value' and not the 'text' in the initial Dropdown this will also let the Dropdown handle displaying the correct value when it isn't active

Here's a slightly simplified version of your code:

```
const currencyDetails = [
    {currencyName: 'United States Dollars', value: 'USD'},
    {currencyName: 'Canadian Dollars', value: 'CDN'}
]
const initialData = {currency: 'USD'}

const CurrencyConverter = () => {

  const handleSelection = (e, value) => {
        console.log(value)
        alert(`"I Chose the value ${value.value}`)
  }

  return (
    <div className="currency-form">
      <Dropdown
        inline
        value={initialData.currency}
      >
        <Dropdown.Menu
        >
          {currencyDetails.map((item) => (
            <Dropdown.Item
              key={item.currencyName}
              value={item.value}
              text={item.currencyName}
              style={{ height: "70px", fontSize: "17px" }}
              onClick={handleSelection}
            />
          ))}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  )
}
```

To read more check out the documentation:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-controlled